# How to extract certain information from a string and create a json object in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, parsing

I made a get request to a website and parsed it using BS4 using 'Html.parser'.  I want to extract the ID, size and availability from the string. I have parsed it down to this final string:

```
'{"id":706816278547,"parent_id":81935859731,"available":false,
"sku":"665570057894","featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":40000,"options":["S"],
"option1":"s","option2":"","option3":"","option4":""},
{"id":707316252691,"parent_id":81935859731,"available":true,
"sku":"665570057900","featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":40000,"options":["M"],
"option1":"m","option2":"","option3":"", "option4":""},
{"id":707316285459,"parent_id":81935859731,"available":true,
"sku":"665570057917","featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":40000,"options":["L"],
"option1":"l","option2":"","option3":"","option4":""},`
{"id":707316318227,"parent_id":81935859731,"available":true,`
"sku":"665570057924","featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":40000,"options":["XL"],
"option1":"xl","option2":"","option3":"","option4":""}'
```

I also tried using the split() method but I get lost and im unable to extract the needed information without creating a cluttered list and getting lost.

I tried using json.loads() so i could just extract the information needed by calling the key and value pairs but i get the following error

```
final_id = 
'{"id":706816278547,"parent_id":81935859731,"available":false,
"sku":"665570057894","featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":40000,"options":["S"],
"option1":"s","option2":"","option3":"","option4":""},
{"id":707316252691,"parent_id":81935859731,"available":true,
"sku":"665570057900","featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":40000,"options":["M"],
"option1":"m","option2":"","option3":"", "option4":""},
{"id":707316285459,"parent_id":81935859731,"available":true,
"sku":"665570057917","featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":40000,"options":["L"],
"option1":"l","option2":"","option3":"","option4":""},`
{"id":707316318227,"parent_id":81935859731,"available":true,`
"sku":"665570057924","featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":40000,"options":["XL"],
"option1":"xl","option2":"","option3":"","option4":""}'

find_id = json.loads(final_id)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 233 (char 232)
```

I want to create a json object for each ID and Size and if that size is available or not.
Any help is welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First thats not a valid json info

second, `json.loads` works for files, so a file containing this info will solve the issue because `null` in json equal `None` in python so `json.load` you can say translate a json file so python understand it, so

```py
import json

with open('sof.json', 'r') as stackof:
    final_id = json.load(stackof)
print(final_id)
```

will output

```
[{'id': 706816278547, 'parent_id': 81935859731, 'available': 'false', 'sku': '665570057894', 'featured_image': None, 'public_title': None, 'requires_shipping': True, 'price': 40000, 'options': ['S'], 'option1': 's', 'option2': '', 'option3': '', 'option4': ''}, {'id': 707316252691, 'parent_id': 81935859731, 'available': True, 'sku': '665570057900', 'featured_image': None, 'public_title': None, 'requires_shipping': True, 'price': 40000, 'options': ['M'], 'option1': 'm', 'option2': '', 'option3': '', 'option4': ''}, {'id': 707316285459, 'parent_id': 81935859731, 'available': True, 'sku': '665570057917', 'featured_image': None, 'public_title': None, 'requires_shipping': True, 'price': 40000, 'options': ['L'], 'option1': 'l', 'option2': '', 'option3': '', 'option4': ''}, {'id': 707316318227, 'parent_id': 81935859731, 'available': True, 'sku': '665570057924', 'featured_image': None, 'public_title': None, 'requires_shipping': True, 'price': 40000, 'options': ['XL'], 'option1': 'xl', 'option2': '', 'option3': '', 'option4': ''}]
```

i made all of them divided into array, so now if you print the first id you should write

```py
print(final_id[0]['id'])
```

output:

```py
706816278547
```

Tell me in the comments if that helped you,

btw click on >> [sof.json](https://gist.github.com/Moha369/76daad5591dd04445703052a15913df6) to see `sof.json`